# Find the number of different integers in an interval in a dynamic array

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Given an array of integers a[i] of length N and Q queries.

1 <= N, Q <= 10^5
1 <= a[i] <= 10^6

There are 2 types of queries. They consists of :

1. Two integers l and r. After processing this query, you have to print the amount of different integers on the interval [l,r]
2. Two integers i and x. After this query, you change the value at ith position to x.

I approached this task by doing a simple sqrt decomposition with sqrt(N) bool tables and combining the results for both queries in O(sqrt(N)).

Unfortunately this didn't work as I can use only up to 512 MB, I used too much memory. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: There tends to be a [tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) for memory and cpu usage. If you're using too much memory (short of actual code optimization / imperformance), then you'll need to store less and calculate on-demand more. I'd probably take some inspiration from binary search and mergesort for a solution.

Comment: For query type 1, do you mean the number of distinct array values in the range `[l, r]` or the number of distinct values among the entries in positions from `[l, r]`? The former is much easier than the latter...

Comment: For type 1, I need the result to the amount of distinct integer values in the range [l, r] after all previous updates.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an array of integers.

For every integer that occurs more than once, make intervals that connect adjacent occurrences.  If 5 appears at positions 2, 10, and 16, for example, then you get intervals [2,10] and [10,16].

Now, for any range [l,r], note the number of occurrences and the number of intervals in that range.  If 5 appears in the range, then number_of_occurrences - number_of_intervals = 1.  If it does not, then that comes out to 0.

If we create intervals for all the integers in the array, then we can use this to count the distinct integers in a range.  The number of integer occurrences in the range is just r-l+1.  Subtract the total number of intervals to get the number of distinct integers.

To quickly calculate the total number of intervals in a range, we can take advantage of the fact that all the intervals have different start positions.
Make an array that contains, at every interval start position, the corresponding end position.  Now to find the total number of intervals in [l,r], you find the count of numbers with positions in [l,r] that are <= r.

To answer *these* questions quickly, make log(N) layers.  In the first layer, we'll make an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree) for each pair of elements.  In the next layer, a tree for each 4, etc.  Any range [l,r] is then exactly covered by O(log N) trees, allowing us the answer the query in O(log<sup>2</sup> N) time.

Implementing this so that you can make changes and answer these queries online is pretty complicated.  You need to track the occurrences of each integer in BSTs so that you can quickly update the interval ranges.  You can do the whole job in O(N log<sup>2</sup> N) time and O(N log N) space, though.